# Space series featuring feathered humanoids, as well as a pig-like race killing humans

Tags: books, space, story-identification

I read a book about a pig-like race killing humans in space there were also avians that looked like humans, with feathers so fine they look like hair. Space series with some humans over everything that speak a different language.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: [Obligatory "Link"](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Pigs_in_Space).

Comment: Are the pig-like and avian species actually true aliens or just evolved/gene-modified humans?

Comment: rimworld featured various humanoid races due to millenia of evolution on the rim

Comment: Poul Anderson had feathered humanoids living on Mars. They featured in more than one story, including "Duel on Syrtis", but that one didn't have anything pig-like iirc.

Comment: So it's basically bacon and eggs in space

Comment: @user163935 Rimworld?  Is that the porn knockoff?  :-)

Answer (score -1):

Is it Enders game?! I was looking for the same book but couldn’t remember the name for the life of me! I think I just found it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _Ender's Game_ matches the book described in the question. For example, does it feature feathered humanoids and a pig-like race killing humans?

Comment: @LogicDictates Given *Ender's Game*, the sequel *Speaker for the Dead* introduces the "Pequeninos" (also referred to as "piggies") who are the intelligent race native to Lusitania.  They kill one of the scientists studying them, but that's a mistake, and it certainly doesn't become common practice.  The rest doesn't match though.